# modify an existing userpool cognito using aws-sam in cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-sam

I need to know if it is possible to control a pre-existing cognito user pool through Cloudformation or AWS SAM, as I can't find any property option where I can declare the cognito user pool id. Here is my template I used, but when I deploy it creates me a new userPool:

`AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: AWS Serverless Backend Wegorent Panel Core
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'

Resources:
MyUserPoolClient:
Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
Properties:
ClientName: MyUserPoolBorrar7abr
UserPoolId: us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx

MyUserPool:
Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
Properties:
UserPoolName: dev-panel-sellers
Policies:
PasswordPolicy:
MinimumLength: 8
RequireLowercase: true
RequireUppercase: true
RequireNumbers: true
RequireSymbols: true
DeletionPolicy: Retain
Outputs:
UserPoolId:
Value: !Ref MyUserPoolClient`

hopefully you can help me by creating an aws sam template that allows me to control a cognito userpool.